Can I only render edges during an animation in Blender 4?
I made this animation using a Text element converted to Mesh, and a Remesh modifier whose Voxel Size value changes through time.

I am interested in rendering only the orange lines seen in this Viewport screenshot, after applying an emission Material to them. I do not want the faces.
So far I have tried a lot of things, such as the Wireframe modifier that didn't seem to make any difference, but I am finding it difficult to find resources applying to Blender 4 online.
I'd rather use Cycles because I'd like to add grain later on (I can't seem to see any grain even with 1 sample - but that's an issue for another question).


You can't see grain (actually called noise here) if you only use an emissive material on the object. Noise is generated by light bouncing off surfaces and not having enough samples. A light source itself is not noisy.

You can use the Wireframe node in the shader to mix between a transparent and emission material. This does however triangulate all of the faces.


